# Complexity of QR-algorithm on a symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

Why does the QR algorithm (for calculating eigenvalues) only require O(m) calculations per step when performed on a symmetric tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: There is hopefuly a link with Cholesky factorisation $LL^T$ where $L$ in this case is a bidiagonal matrix (diagonal+subdiagonal) which can be obtained in $O(n)$ operations (I am unable to find references quickly)

Comment: Chapter 4.6 of http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf might be helpful to you.